# Access current instance of a fragment from FirebaseMessagingService class

Tags: firebase, android-fragments

I want to access the instance of my fragment from FirebaseMessagingService class but it doesn't seem possible as FragmentManager can't be accessed from FirebaseMessagingService class therefore making

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag
```

not applicable. Any suggestions on how to access the current instance of the fragment from FirebaseMessagingService class would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using EventBus library by subscribing my fragment as a listener to the FirebaseMessagingService class method.